# How to write a function to find positions of substring within a larger string without using the 'find' function?

Tags: python, string, list, substring, linear-search

I have just recently started using python and I am extremely new to python and coding in general and I'm in a class where we have been given the assignment to find a function in Python that takes two strings of DNA sequence (say string1 and string2) as input and returns a list of the position(s) where string2 is present as a substring of string1. And since we're supposed to be becoming familiar with how coding works, we can't use the "find" built-in function. I'm really confused on how to even start this problem. But this is what I have so far:

```
def linear(seq, sub):
    positions = [0]
    for i in range(len(sub)):
        if seq[i:i+len(sub)] == sub:
             positions[0]+=1
    return( positions )
```

I get an error when I put this in but I should get out a list of the positions where the substring occurs. If someone can guide me in which direction I should be going, that would be really helpful.

As an example if the sequence is 'ATTCCATGGACCTAGTCAT' and the substring I want to find is 'CAT', then the output should be [5,17]

Comment: Since this is an assignment, no one is going to give you the answer. Specifically, provide the error you are receiving and someone may help you work through the error.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it can't be `[5,17]` as indexing in python starts at 0, it should be `[4,16]`. You can use a `for` loop to go through the indexes till the last index minus the length of the substring plus `1` in order not to get out of range. Then you check if the slice of the string, which is the current index till the current index plus the length of the substring (if it is `'CAT'` then you get every slice of the length of `3` of the string), is equal to the substring. If so then append the index to the index list.

```
def find(st,sub):
    list_of_pos=[]
    for i in range(len(st)-len(sub)+1):
        if st[i:i+len(sub)]==sub:
            list_of_pos.append(i)
    return list_of_pos
```

You can make it more compact if you use list comprehension:

```
def find(st,sub):
    return [i for i in range(len(st)-len(sub)+1) if st[i:i+len(sub)]==sub]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very helpful!